# Need advice on MongoDB Schema for Chat App. Embedded vs Related Documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I'm starting a MongoDB project just for kicks and as a chance to learn MongoDB/NoSQL schemas.  It'll be a live chat app and the stack includes: Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2, Devise, Mongoid/MongoDB, CarrierWave, Redis, JQuery.

I'll be handling the live chat polling/message queueing separately.  Not sure how yet, either Node.js, APE or custom EventMachine app.  But in regards to Mongo, I'm thinking to use it for everything else in the app, specifically chat logs and historical transcripts.

My question is how best to design the schema as all my previous experience has been with MySQL and relational DB schema's.  And as a sub-question, when is it best to us embedded documents vs related documents.

The app will have:

- Multiple accounts which have multiple rooms
- Multiple rooms
- Multiple users per room
- List of rooms a user is allowed to be in
- Multiple user chats per room
- Searchable chat logs on a per room and per user basis
- Optional file attachment for a given chat

Given Mongo (at least last time I checked) has a document limit of 4MB, I don't think having a collection for rooms and storing all room chats as embedded documents would work out so well.

From what I've thought about so far, I'm thinking of doing something like:

- A collection for accounts
- A collection for rooms

  - Each room relates back to an account
  - Related documents in chats collections for all chat messages in the room
  - Embedded Document listing all users currently in the room
- A collection for users

  - Embedded Document listing all the rooms the user is currently in
  - Embedded Document listing all the rooms the user is allowed to be in
- A collection for chats

  - Each chat relates back to a room in the rooms collection
  - Each chat relates back to a user in the users collection
  - Embedded document with info about optional uploaded file attachment.

My main concern is how far do I go until this ends up looking like a relational schema and I defeat the purpose? There is definitely more relating than embedding going on.

Another concern is that referencing related documents is much slower than accessing embedded documents I've heard.

I want to make generic queries such as:

- Give me all rooms for an account
- Give me all chats in a room (or filtered via date range)
- Give me all chats from a specific user
- Give me all uploaded files in a given room or for a given org
- etc

Any suggestions on how to structure the schema efficiently in a way that scales? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Which direction did you choose in the end? How did you handle data integrity with related documents in Mongo? Did you end up having any date integrity issues with Mongo and if so how did you get around them?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're pretty much on the right track. I'd use a [capped collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) for chat lines, with each line containing the user ID, room ID, timestamp, and what was said. This data would expire once the capped collection's "end" is reached, so if you needed a historical log you'd want to copy data out of the capped collection into a "log" collection periodically, but capped collections are specifically designed for logging-style applications where you aren't going to be deleting documents, and insertion order matters. In the case of chat, it's a perfect match.

The only other change I'd suggest would be to maintain uploads in a separate collection, as well.

Comment: Good idea Chris, I was just looking at capped collections too.

Comment: I suppose if I had a capped collection and a regular log collection, I could just write twice to both collections.  That of course would double the write load. But also, would I need a capped collection for more recent chats if I have a separate chat server build in node.js or orbited?  I suppose that would not only handle all the async messages but I could then write those (one at a time or in batches) into Mongodb and the chats collection and not need to have a capped collection.  What do you think?

Comment: Writes in MongoDB are asynchronous by default, so I wouldn't worry about writing twice. The attraction of a capped collection is that it can be *very* fast because of the assumptions it makes. If you're going to be frequently pulling the last lines in insert order, a capped collection makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I am a big fan of mongodb as a document database aswell. But are you sure you are using mongodb for the right reason?  What is mongodb powerful at?

Its a subjective question but for me in-place (atomic) updates over documents is what makes mongodb powerful. And I can't really see you using it that much. And on top of that you are hitting the document size limit problem aswell.(With experience I can tell you that embedding files to mongodb is not a good idea). You want to have a live chat application on top of database too.

Your document schema's seems logical. But I wouldn't go with mongodb for this kind of project where your application heavily depends on inserts. I would go for CouchDB.

With CouchDB you wouldn't have to worry about attachments problem, you can embed them easily. "_changes" would make your life much much easier to eighter build a live chat application / long pooling / feeding search engine (if you want to implement one).

And I saw an [open source showcase project](http://www.couchone.com/case-study-anologue) in couchone. It has some similarities with your goals: [Anologue](http://www.anologue.com/). You should check it out.

PS : Sorry it was a little off topic but I couldn't hold myself.